# Laurent series of $f(z)=\frac{1}{z^{2}\sinh(z)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, analysis, power-series, laurent-series

I would really appreciate if you could help me understand this. So, I’m at this point

$\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^{2m+3}}{(2m+1)!}\sum_{k=-2}^{\infty}c_{2k+1}z^{2k+1}=1$

But I don’t really know how to continue. How do I multiply these two power series? How do I get the coefficients of the Laurent series?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you really want to comput the Laurent series of $\frac1{z^2\sinh(z)}$? Or is this meant to help you to solve another problem?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I have to use the first three terms of the Laurent series of that function to show that $\oint_C f(z) \,dz = -\frac{\pi i}{3}$ where C = {z : |z| = 1}

Comment: I have provided an answer to *thatt* question and I suggest that you edit your question so that it becomes cler that all you want is the coefficient of $z^{-1}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $z\ne0$, let$$g(z)=\frac{\sinh(z)}z=1+\frac1{3!}z^2+\frac1{5!}z^4+\cdots$$and note that $g$ is an even function. Let$$h(z)=\frac1{g(z)}=\frac z{\sinh(z)}.$$Then $h$ is an even function too. Let $1+a_2z^2+a_4z^4+\cdots$ be its Taylor series centered at $0$. Then\begin{align}1&=g(z)h(z)\\&=\left(1+\frac1{3!}z^2+\frac1{5!}z^4+\cdots\right)\left(1+a_2z^2+a_4z^4+\cdots\right)\\&=1+\left(a_2+\frac16\right)z^2+\cdots\end{align}and therefore $a_2=-\frac16$. Therefore$$\frac1{z^2\sinh(z)}=\frac{h(z)}{z^3}=\frac1{z^3}-\frac1{6z}+\cdots$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Use the first three terms of the expansion in power series of $\sinh z$:
$$\sinh z=z+\frac{z^3}{3!}+\frac{z^5}{5!}+o(z^5),$$
use it in the function:
$$f(z)=\frac1{z^2\sinh z}=\frac1{z^3}\frac1{1+\cfrac{z^2}{6}+\cfrac{z^4}{120}+o(z^4)}$$
 and perform the division of $1$ by $1+\dfrac{z^2}{6}+\dfrac{z^4}{120}$ by *increasing powers* of $z$ up to degree $4$.